# plist or text file

Tags: ios, ios4, plist

Hi I have to create a table with some data. For the data, I read online that you can create a plist. But I wasn't sure how it worked? Does it only work in navigation based? I created a view based app, and used a text file instead, and then read from the file into an array which loads the data to my table. It works fine. But I'm just curious when/why/how would you use plists? I am programming in iOS for iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Plists are a special kind of XML. They are easy to create in Xcode and can all sorts of data types including strings, numbers, and booleans. It can organize those items into dictionaries and or arrays.  They are always the best route for small or medium amounts of data.  And they can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Plists are great, mostly because they're invisible if you just want to archive some standard Cocoa data structures/holders (`NSArray`,`NSDictionary`,`NSString`,`NSNumber`, etc...) to a file and back out again without missing a beat.

IMHO, the simplest use for plists is the [`writeToFile:atomically:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method on `NSDictionary`, and the corresponding `initWithContentsOfFile:`. These let you store your (relatively primitive) data in an ad-hoc plist, without even having to know that's what it will be stored as.

Comment: so how do i create a plist then? at the moment i typed my data into a text file and added it to my project, from where I read it into an array and store it to the table. How to achieve the same for plist? how is it created thanks

Comment: Just add a new file to your Xcode project, and select Property List as its type. Xcode has a built-in plist editor (in 4.0+, at least).

Comment: thanks but i did that and a plist is added but its not editable, i can't do anything on it.

Comment: Try ctrl-clicking and look for an option like 'add a row/field'?

Comment: hi, i started with text files, as i have got a long list of questions as my data, i.e. not just one word lines, so i preferred text files and my program is working fine. However, before moving on i just want to be sure that it will work on ipjone/ipad? as in text files which are at the moment in my project, they will be compatible once i load my project(app) onto the iPhone/ipad?